# Indefinite Plural VS Indefinite Singular for stating general facts, properties, etc

Tags: articles, definite-articles, indefinite-articles

Is there any nuance in the two sentences below if I want to state a general fact about **cars** ?

A) **Cars** have 4 wheels.

B) **A car** has 4 wheels.

The question above is also a question to itself.

So can I say "...if I want to state a general fact about **a car**" instead of ".....**cars**"?

Comment: These are different kinds of [Generic Noun Phrases](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/000001.html). There are several varieties in English.

Comment: Unsure what's being asked. Either works. I guess the real question is "Who's the audience?" and "Why would the audience care about the nuance?"

Comment: @JohnLawler, Thanks. That is the kind of answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

> A) **Cars** have 4 wheels

This asserts a true statement about (implicitly) all cars. But some cars might have 3 wheels. And theoretically most cars have 5 wheels (spare in trunk).

> B) **A car** has 4 wheels

Also implies the same thing: A car, random car that you find on the street, has 4 wheels.

Neither offer much opportunity to offer variance to the statement.